# database for c# form

Tags: c#, database, forms

I am doing a school project in C# apps and I decided to create a ticketing system. 
I want to impress my teacher (^^) so I decided to add a database for my app. 
I have a month to do this so i think I can learn it since I don't have any prior experience with databases.

Could you tell me how to do it? Below is my app, I want to send the info in the `TextBox` to a database 
[image]

I already followed the instructions in MSDN which basically tells you how to add a data source in your app. I added northwind dataset to my app, but I don't know what to do with it and how will it be useful with my app...

Comment: I don't think your professor would be all that impressed with this post.  I agree with hivie7510 the UI is nice.

Comment: @Roj Beraña
: adding northwind isn't going to be of a great deal of use. You need to decide what you are storing in a  DB, then create a schema to model this and create a database, then create a datasource to you database. The dataset can then be used to retrieve  data from the database into memory, alter it and then save it back to the database.

Comment: pedantic point: is it 'The theatre of dreams' or just A 'threatre of dreams'? what if your prof. doesn't like foozeball?  ;)

Comment: You are going to have to look up tutorials on how to use whatever you decide to use. That much information is outside the scope of the Q&A model of Stackoverflow. Most databases require a service running, except for some that are serverless/embedded (like SQLite). Make sure you pick something your teacher is going to be able to run without installing anything so that they can actually examine and grade your work.

Comment: he'll have plenty of time in his career to drown in sqlserver. This time should be savored to learn - not to just be employable.

Comment: i want to create a database and read and write info into it by gathering what it is written in the textbox. but upon reading some tutorials in sql, it just gave me headaches..i still dont understand it
@Mitch Wheat... to impress my prof is to add a database in my app that he hasnt taught to us yet ^^

Comment: @ adymitruk: "It is hard to apply oneself to study when there is no money to pay for food and lodging"

Comment: Good old FUD from MS. Do you think for yourself or do you let MS do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a SQL backend, you can use SQLite quite easily. SQLite is simply a file that resides on the local system, so it is totally portable/deployable with your application. It comes with the caveat that the database is not shared between users. It is a single user database. Two people running an application based on SQLite will not share data. For a uni assignment, this is probably not going to be a big deal.

You could also use SQL Server CE (compact edition), which is a stripped down SQL Server implementation which is similar to SQLite (local, embedded, single user). This will allow you to use Visual Studio database tools to design your database.

Once you have a database embedded within your application, you need to design a schema to hold on to this information. If your screenshot is the only data you need to save, a table like the following should do the trick:

```
TABLE PERSON
    COLUMN name     varchar(100) 
    COLUMN address  varchar(200)
    COLUMN email    varchar(100)
    COLUMN mobile   varchar(15)
```

You will need to investigate how to create tables in SQL. That should guide you in what you need though. Visual Studio (some versions), also have a database browser/designer.

Then you need to decide how you want to communicate with the database. You have several options.

- Linq 2 SQL
- Entity
- DataTables

Scott Gu has an excellent series on how to use [Linq 2 SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) which I would highly recommend reading. It will go the majority of the way to helping you get to where you need.

So now that you have a SQL database and a provider, you can start trying to wire up the database to the form. This is where databinding comes in. You can drag a Data Source onto a form (which is your Person table), and wire up the table to your text fields. There are many examples on the net how to do this.

If you want to take it a step further, look into the ErrorProvider control. It will allow you to bind validation to your data source and text fields. Once again, a few google searches should point you in the right direction.

I haven't provided code samples because this is homework. If you want to impress your teacher, you will do so by truly understanding the technology you're trying to use. These are just pointers in the right direction so you know what it is you can investigate. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty broad question, is there something specifically that you need help with?  Like connect to the database, use a datareader, etc...?

Comment: i want to create a database and read and write info into it by gathering what it is written in the textbox. but upon reading some tutorials in sql, it just gave me headaches..i still dont understand it.

Comment: Roj, I understand, believe me.  What I recommend is that you use the AdventureWorks database from Microsoft Samples.  This database already has a person table (with data) and it has all of the stored procedures to work with it.  You can use it as is, or customize it as you want.  That way you can worry about the code, since I am assuming that this is not a database class.  I think when you install Sql Server Express, you get the AW database.  It's free anyhow.  Then look at examples for SqlConnection,SqlCommand,SqlParameter and SqlDataReader.  That is the bare minimum that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impress your teacher, don't refer to MSDN. Use something like couchdb. Don't get caught up in the "prescribed " .net ecosystem.

Comment: 'prescribed'? lol! - there's nothing wrong with SQL Server. Its a great product.

Comment: Of course they could use Cassandra, MongoDB or any other buzz word based database of the minute, but they are students.  I think they should stick with something that is well documented (MSSQL,MySQL,Oracle...) to make sure they can do it.  A major component of any assignment is completing it.  I think a wild goose chase down the buzzword broadway would be inappropriate and unhelpful.  Wow, that really sounded soapboxy.  Sorry

Comment: SQL Server may be a good product, but it likely won't impress his teacher that much (and CouchDB or Redis or <insert noSQL here> certainly will =))

Comment: IFF they can complete it.  If they cannot grasp SQL, how will they be able to do a document or object database?  I think the cool factor is great once they get past the fundamentals. I think it does someone junior a great disservice steering them away from learning the fundamental tools of the language.  In .NET there are providers for those other databases, but you have to know what you are doing to consume them.  Suitable examples are a must at their academic level, and MSDN is full of them.

Comment: But, as Joel B Fant suggested, using something that don't need a service (like SQLite) may be more suitable, and give less headaches on deliverings

Comment: I am all for the NOSQL movement for certain things, but you haven't stated any of them.  So other than cool, what justification would they have to tell their teacher other than someone recommended.  Just like when my engineers want to use some new framework, I have to ask them what problem does using it solve.  If they cannot answer it, then they cannot use it. This project (from looking at the form) is not a high read/write system, so NOSQL db's would do little more than add confusion.

Comment: SQL lite would be perfect for them, unless they need stored procedures.  At least I don't think it supports stored procedures.

Comment: Its funny, we have had this long winded conversation and I don't think they are even a part of it.

Comment: NoSQL is not just a 'cool' thing, it's not that complex, it's just different than what's on MSDN. And, judging by what the kid asked, I think he won't be needing Stored Procedures soon... anyway, I can't think of one single case they would be necessary ;)

Comment: TL;DR haha I think you guys scared him =P

Comment: This is not about whether sqlserver is a great product or not. It's about a student wanting to do more. MSDN stifles learning. It's a company out to make money with little regard to your well-being. You should be ashamed of yourselves. This further goes to show how SO adds nothing to the community.

Comment: NoSQL  is likely to be a 'flash in the pan'

Comment: @adymitruk: "You should be ashamed of yourselves" - don't be so melodramatic and naive. Companies make money; that's why they exist. To a large extent market forces drive competing products to get better.

Comment: They make money at any cost. The microsoft ecosystem is one that profits with certifications and maintenance contacts on government level inefficient organizations - not where competition would kill them. How many start ups use ms? What makes you think I'm naive? Look in the mirror.

Comment: -1 since I believe this is a horrible application of document store especially for a uni student. "Dont get caught up in the prescribed .net ecosystem"? The assignment is based around USING .net. There are built in SQL providers for most of the major sql products. Just because you hate a company for whatever reason (misguided or other), does not mean that many people find their products useful.

Comment: Use something that is more than f1 away. I love .net.